# Sql read specific row value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use a single query to get the first 5 values as a single row of results. I am aware that the following does not work but I think it gives a good example of what I am trying to achieve

```
SELECT
   idimage[0] AS Row1, //idimage row 1 value
   idimage[1] AS Row2, //idimage row 2 value
   idimage[2] AS Row3, //idimage row 3 value
   idimage[3] AS Row4, //idimage row 4 value
   idimage[4] AS Row5  //idimage row 5 value
FROM
IMAGES
```

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this. I am sure the syntax must be pretty simple but i cant seem to find it.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Sql-Server (Microsoft)

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then idimage end) as idimage1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then idimage end) as idimage2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then idimage end) as idimage3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then idimage end) as idimage4,
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then idimage end) as idimage5       
from (select i.*, row_number() over (order by ?) as seqnm
      from images i
     ) i;
```

Note that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The `?` in the `order by` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, maybe you can use some subquery this way:

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT idimage from IMAGES ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY ) AS ROW1, 
 (SELECT idimage from IMAGES ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS ROW2, 
 (SELECT idimage from IMAGES ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS ROW3, 
 (SELECT idimage from IMAGES ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 3 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS ROW4, 
 (SELECT idimage from IMAGES ORDER BY id desc OFFSET 4 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS ROW5
FROM IMAGES;
```

Comment: Thank you but this assumes i know the top 5 id's, which may change if the older records have been removed

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that, I'll change the query then. Do you want to be ordered by id descending?

Answer (score 0):

use LIMIT and ORDER BY to restrict your rows to 5.
Check for instance [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv) to concatanate the resulting rows